# How can we make use of CoreML framework for handwriting detection in iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, machine-learning, ios11, coreml

How can I use **`CoreML`** to convert handwritten image to text?

Comment: But I believe the reason that this was down voted is because Stack Overflow is not meant to be a resource for finding APIs. Typically we support you attempting to find a step in the right direction and asking for help on that.

Comment: Updated the question. I believe now this should make sense to post a question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Typically you shouldn't ask for recommendations for frameworks to use here, the reasoning is that third-party frameworks do not actually assist you in learning to code something. They just do it for you. `CoreML` is not able to read handwriting at this point, but it is possible that Apple will dive into this in future updates to the `CoreML` framework.

Comment: By the term framework was for apple inbuilt frameworks and not third party SDKs.

Comment: I understand! CoreML is the closest framework to what you need, but at this point, there are no Apple frameworks that are able to transcribe handwriting. I know that Apple has done it (for example on the Apple watch to write a text), but that code is proprietary at the moment. We may get it next year!

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is to use the Vision framework to detect text in your image, which gives you a list of rectangles. Then use a neural network that's trained to recognize text on each of these rectangles. You can use Vision to drive Core ML but you still need to provide it with a suitable neural network yourself. You can find pretrained networks for this on the web, but you'll need to convert them to Core ML using the tools supplied by Apple.

Comment: Do you have a link to such a pre-trained model? All I can find is references to the MNIST dataset...

Comment: These days I would use Google's ML Kit, which has this kind of functionality built in. It's _really_ hard to train your own handwriting recognition model.